# How to empty the Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using the function `Array.Clear()` to empty an array, but it generates an error.
This is the code I was using:

```
private int[] activeFielderNumber = new int[10];
private string[] activeFielderAction = new string[10];  
....
...
....
Array.Clear(activeFielderNumber, 0, activeFielderNumber.Length);
Array.Clear(activeFielderAction, "", activeFielderAction.Length);
```

The error is:

```
error CS0103: The name `Array' does not exist in the current context
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error would indicate the class Array is not in scope.  Could you expand your sample code to show at least the method declarations and maybe your usings?

Comment: There are multiple ways to clearing arrays. Even though Array.Clear() is the simplest in terms of code, if you're interested [here are other methods](http://blogs.davelozinski.com/curiousconsultant/csharp-net-fastest-way-to-clear-collections)

Answer (score 11):

did you use

```
using System;
```

and one more point to correct:

```
Array.Clear(activeFielderAction, "", activeFielderAction.Length);
```

it should be

```
Array.Clear(activeFielderAction, 0, activeFielderAction.Length);
```

The last two parameters are the index-ranges to be cleared.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
Array.Clear(yourArray, 0, yourArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I am using Array.Clear() function to empty array. But it was throwing error

No, i was not. The Clear function was not throwing an error, the COMPILER was.

> error CS0103: The name `Array' does not exist in the current context

Google says the following when we look for CS0103:

[Compiler Error CS0103 (C#) at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> An attempt was made to use a name that does not exist in the class,
>   namespace, or scope. Check the spelling of the name and check your
>   using statements and assembly references to make sure that the name
>   you are trying to use is available. One common mistake is to declare a
>   variable within a loop or a try block and then attempt to access it
>   from an enclosing code block or another code block, as shown in the
>   following example.

Translates into: Array is not found in the context. Are you missing a "using" statement?

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] activeFielderNumber = new int[10];
string[] activeFielderAction = new string[10];  

Array.Clear(activeFielderNumber, 0, activeFielderNumber.Length);
Array.Clear(activeFielderAction, 0, activeFielderAction.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Clear()` method only resets the array to its default state.

Based on the statement

`Array.Clear(activeFielderAction, "", activeFielderAction.Length);` we may get an error.

The actual statement should be

`Array.Clear(activeFielderAction, 0, activeFielderAction.Length);`

Also check whether you are `importing Using.System;` namespace.

Try the below code.

```
int[] activeFielderNumber = new int[10];
activeFielderNumber[1] = 10;
activeFielderNumber[2] = 20;

string[] activeFielderAction = new string[10];
Array.Clear(activeFielderNumber, 0, activeFielderNumber.Length);
Array.Clear(activeFielderAction, 0, activeFielderAction.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough points to post a comment, so have to provide an "answer" here... for any "speed junkies" out there, there are numerous ways to clear an array (not just [Array.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) [as demonstrated here](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-clear-collections), but typically [Array.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the easiest and fastest.

Here are 3 ways that were tested to clear an array ([direct from the site](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-clear-collections)) where "o1" is the object array:

```
for (int x = 0; x < MAX; x++)
{
    o1[x] = null;
}

Array.Clear(o1, 0, o1.Length);

Parallel.For(0, MAX, x =>
{   //arrays are thread safe if only one thread is writing to an index
    o1[x] = null;
});
```

I thought it was interesting reading as I never gave a second thought to trying another way (especially using a parallel loop) other than [Array.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) though.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Array.Clear(activeFielderAction, "", activeFielderAction.Length);
```

is not a valid use of [Array.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx) - the middle parameter needs to be an int, like you have on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply set Array object reference to null example

String url = "http://localhost/RestWebService/employee?" name + "," + id;
  String[] arr = url.Split('?');

```
        arr = null;
        arr = url.Split('?');
```

Thats all